# Debug: If Not IsError() Then

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I've set up the macro below which compares a column of codes (Instrument), one row at a time, by searching another column in a different workbook. If no code matches, the macro will alter a date in the first workbook by going back one day, which then changes the original code (in Instrument), and searches again. If a code is found, the macro should end by moving to the next row down:

```
Sub YTM()

    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(5, 24).End(xlDown).Row
    'N = 7
    Dim c As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    For Each c In Range("X2:X" & N)
        c.Select
        If IsError(c) Then
            For x = 1 To 14
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -18).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -18).Value - x/x
                If Not IsError(c) Then Exit For
            Next x
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

However, my VBA discontinues and wants me to debug the following code:

```
If Not IsError(c) Then
```

I can't seem to work out why. I'm quite new to VBA, so I'm sure this issue is trivial. If further context is needed for clarity I am happy to oblige. All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: x/x is always returning 1: what’s the point of that? And you write _” by searching another column in a different workbook”_ but I can’t see where it happens in your code

Answer (score 0):

A bit more explicit about using `Value`, and without any Select/Activate:

```
Sub YTM()


    Dim N As Long, c As Range, x As Long

    N = Cells(5, 24).End(xlDown).Row

    For Each c In Range("X2:X" & N).Cells
        If IsError(c.Value) Then
            For x = 1 To 14
                 c.Offset(0, -18).Value = c.Offset(0, -18).Value - 1
                 DoEvents 'allow for calculation...
                 If Not IsError(c.Value) Then Exit For
            Next x
        End If
     Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR, I’d say there’s some calculations triggered by changing a cell 18 columns left of current cell and affecting this latter content

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply, only just getting back to the project now. I implemented the code, however a similar debugging is required for "DoEvents". As such, I might have to check my code actually lines up well with the workbooks.

Comment: `DoEvents` is built-in to Excel VBA so it's difficult to image how that's triggering an error.